# When I access a server that has multiple DNS IP addresses, which one do I use?

Tags: networking, dns, scaling

Right now if I run host `superuser.com`, I get:

```
superuser.com has address 151.101.193.69
superuser.com has address 151.101.1.69
superuser.com has address 151.101.65.69
superuser.com has address 151.101.129.69
```

So if I am using a web browser or a command line client, which one does it connect to?

And how does that work differently if I am somewhere else in the world?

Comment: as for geolocation, that is generally handled by the DNS server. those are the location-weighted responses you are looking at. you don't have to choose the correct one for your location.  that happens up-stream. as for which IP to use, that appears to be application-specific. the standard network library for *nix includes a function `getHostByName(...)` which like DNS, returns a list if there are multiple responses. https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html

Answer (score 2):

> So if I am using a web browser or a command line client, which one does it connect to?

Depends on the OS and/or the program.

For a list of addresses of the same type (e.g. multiple A records), it's either the first one or a random one from the list.

(There's no defined order between records so "first" is just whatever happened to be put into the packet first. Some DNS servers are known to deliberately shuffle the answers they send, to 'help' old clients that always take the first record.)

For IPv4 vs IPv6 (A vs AAAA records), web browsers often try both at once (i.e. one of each type) and use whichever connection succeeds first, closing the other one. Simpler clients follow the prioritization set by the OS, which is typically global IPv6 addresses first, then IPv4 addresses.

> And how does that work differently if I am somewhere else in the world?

If you get the same answer, then your client behaves the same way, no matter where you are. In the simplest case, that answer might indeed point to a server far away from you.

Some websites use anycast, where the same IP address leads to different physical locations, getting you to the closest instance every time. If you're in USA, the IP addresses of superuser.com lead you to servers in the USA; in Europe the same addresses lead to servers in Germany.

For some websites (especially those using CDN services), DNS answers are dynamically generated – the server doesn't just read out the same address from its database but picks different ones every time, often using IP "geolocation" to choose servers closest to you. For example, google.com will appear to have different A/AAAA records when queried from different countries.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard. It's left up to the implementations. Some implementations will take the first one listed. Some implementations may pick one at random.

The closest thing to a standard in this regard might be "Happy Eyeballs", where, if both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses are returned in the DNS lookup, some systems will do "connection racing": attempt to connect to one of each at the same time, and accept whichever connection gets established first (and reset the loser).